# Generic object in Android Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

```
public class MyClassActivity<T> extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // todo..
    }
```

It is possible?

How startActivity with T object?

Comment: You start the activity based on the `class` object of it in the Intent, therefore I vote for *no*.

Comment: I think you can but using an array instead, but u should use same xml for some activities